# Simplifying Static Const Member Definitions of Templated Class

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to define a set of static const member variables of a class clearly, but I feel like my code is being overwhelmed by boilerplate syntax.

Here's an example:

```
template <typename InputT, typename OutputT>
class MyClassWithALongName {
    public:
        static const std::string kParameterOne;
        static const std::string kParameterTwo;
        static const std::string kParameterThree;
};

template <typename InputT, typename OutputT>
const std::string MyClassWithALongName<InputT, OutputT>::kParameterOne = "The quick brown fox";
template <typename InputT, typename OutputT>
const std::string MyClassWithALongName<InputT, OutputT>::kParameterTwo = " jumps over";
template <typename InputT, typename OutputT>
const std::string MyClassWithALongName<InputT, OutputT>::kParameterThree = " the lazy dog.";
```

The problem that I see is that the important information to the reader

```
const std::string MyClassWithALongName::kParameterOne = "The quick brown fox";
const std::string MyClassWithALongName::kParameterTwo = " jumps over";
const std::string MyClassWithALongName::kParameterThree = " the lazy dog.";
```

is being swallowed up by all the template syntax.  When the names are shorter, putting everything on one line helps to visually group the boilerplate template syntax and allow the reader to automatically filter it out.  However, with longer names that's not an option.

Is there a more readable way of defining these constants in this case that makes the important information more clear?

Bonus: is there some magic way to get rid of the templating altogether for these static const values? Obviously they don't actually depend on the template types at all.

Comment: Is it possible to use C++17? If so the solution is pretty simple.

Comment: I would love to see a C++17 solution for my own edification, however my current environment doesn't allow me to use it.

Comment: I'll add it so you can at least see what you can do eventually.

Comment: Thank you! I am not very familiar with C++17 yet, but what I have seen of it is very nice.

Comment: Could it be (inline) function instead?

Comment: @Jarod42 constexpr is inline implicitly

Comment: @Jarod42 Replace the variables with functions?  I'm worried that might not be the best style either, because in practice they are simply constant values.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++17 you can use a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) and make it [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).  This lets you define the variable inside the class and you don't need to provide a definition outside of the class (gets rid of all that template muck).  That would make the code look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

template <typename InputT, typename OutputT>
class MyClassWithALongName {
    public:
        static constexpr std::string_view kParameterOne = "The quick brown fox";
        static constexpr std::string_view kParameterTwo = " jumps over";
        static constexpr std::string_view kParameterThree = " the lazy dog.";
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << MyClassWithALongName<int, int>::kParameterOne;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89de360b417ae16e)

Comment: Is string_view a must here?

Comment: @Oblivion If they want all of the string functionality it is.  If not they can be replaced with `static constexpr const char* member_name` or `static constexpr const char member_name[]`

Comment: so std::string itself cannot be used then?

Comment: @Oblivion Not when using `constexpr`.  It does not have a `constexpr` constructor.  Robert Andrzejuk shows in their answer how you could use a `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 2):

With C++17 inline variables can be used:

```
template< typename InputT, typename OutputT >
class MyClassWithALongName
{
public:
    static inline const std::string kParameterOne   = "The quick brown fox";
    static inline const std::string kParameterTwo   = " jumps over";
    static inline const std::string kParameterThree = " the lazy dog.";
};
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is a static variable. I think that's why `inline` was introduced.

Comment: The inline specifier, when used in a decl-specifier-seq of a variable with static storage duration (static class member or namespace-scope variable), declares the variable to be an inline variable.

A static member variable (but not a namespace-scope variable) declared constexpr is implicitly an inline variable. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

Answer (score 1):

Pre C++17, you might use function instead of member data to allow inline definition:

```cpp
template <typename InputT, typename OutputT>
class MyClassWithALongName
{
public:
    static const std::string& kParameterOne()   { static const std::string s = "The quick brown fox"; return s; }
    static const std::string& kParameterTwo()   { static const std::string s = " jumps over";         return s; }
    static const std::string& kParameterThree() { static const std::string s = " the lazy dog.";      return s; }
};
```

Comment: Well this does eliminate the template code, but it also adds a lot of function-related boilerplate code in its place.  E.g. the repetition of `static const std::string` is very burdensome.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see better way (in C++11) to avoid the boilerplate. In your case, you could inherit from a non template class.